# Android :camera ui disapering on camera starts but the preview remains

Tags: android, camera

This is the main activity where the XML file is launched: VideoCaptureActivity.java:

```
public class VideoCaptureActivity extends Activity 
{
    private static final String TAG = "VideoCaptureActivity";

    Camera camera;
    ImageButton recordButton;
    ImageButton stopButton;enter code here
    ImageButton back;
    Button flash;
    Button flashoff;
    Button flip;
    SeekBar sb;
    FrameLayout cameraPreviewFrame;
    CameraPreview cameraPreview;
    MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
    private Spinner spinner1;
    private Timer myTimer;
    File file;
    int currentZoomLevel = 0;
    int maxZoomLevel = 0;
    int MAX_ZOOM=15;
    int fcamera =0;
    Size temp;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        super.setContentView(R.layout.video_capture);

        //      this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        //      this.mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
        //      this.mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        //      this.mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        //      this.mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
        //      this.mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        this.cameraPreviewFrame = (FrameLayout)super.findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        this.recordButton = (ImageButton)super.findViewById(R.id.recordButton);
        this.stopButton = (ImageButton)super.findViewById(R.id.stopButton);
        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        back =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.back);
        this.flash=(Button)findViewById(R.id.flashon);
        this.flashoff=(Button)findViewById(R.id.fashoff);
        this.sb = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        this.sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener( new seekListener() );

        this.toggleButtons(false);
        // we'll enable this button once the camera is ready
        this.recordButton.setEnabled(false);

        //  this.flash.setEnabled(false);       
        stopButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopRecording(v);
            }
        });

        flash.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                flashLightOn(v );
            }
        });
        flashoff.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                flashLightOff(v );
            }
        });


        back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //DatePicker dp = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
                Intent intent = new Intent(VideoCaptureActivity.this ,MainGrid.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                startActivity(intent);              
            }
        });
    }

    void toggleButtons(boolean recording) {
        this.recordButton.setEnabled(!recording);
        this.recordButton.setVisibility(recording ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        this.stopButton.setEnabled(recording);
        this.stopButton.setVisibility(recording ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }


    public void flashLightOn(View view) {
        // this.flash.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        this.flash.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        try {
            if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                    PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)) {
                //  camera = Camera.open();
                Parameters p = camera.getParameters();    

                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                camera.setParameters(p);
                //                camera.startPreview();


            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Exception flashLightOn()",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    public void flashLightOff(View view) {
        // this.flash.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        this.flash.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        try {
            if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                    PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)) {
                Parameters p = camera.getParameters();    

                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                camera.setParameters(p);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Exception flashLightOff",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // initialize the camera in background, as this may take a while
        //        try {
        //            Camera camera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
        //            sb.setMax(camera.getParameters().getMaxZoom());
        //            sb.setProgress(0);
        //        //    Camera camera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
        //          
        //        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        //            Log.wtf(TAG, "Failed to get camera", e);
        //        }
        //        if (camera == null) {
        //            Toast.makeText(VideoCaptureActivity.this, R.string.cannot_record,
        //                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //        } else {
        //            VideoCaptureActivity.this.initCamera(camera);
        //        }
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Camera>() {

            @Override
            protected Camera doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    Camera camera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);
                    sb.setMax(camera.getParameters().getMaxZoom());
                    sb.setProgress(0);
                    //  Camera camera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
                    return camera == null ? Camera.open(0) : camera;

                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                    Log.wtf(TAG, "Failed to get camera", e);
                    return null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Camera camera) {
                if (camera == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(VideoCaptureActivity.this, R.string.cannot_record,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    initCamera(camera);
                }
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    void initCamera(Camera camera) {
        // we now have the camera
        Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
        List<Size> previewSize = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        temp = previewSize.get(0);
        //        for (int i =0; i<previewSize.size(); i++)
        //        {
        //          
        //        }
        this.camera = camera;
        // create a preview for our camera
        this.cameraPreview = new CameraPreview( VideoCaptureActivity.this,camera);
        // add the preview to our preview frame
        this.cameraPreviewFrame.addView(this.cameraPreview);
        // enable just the record button
        this.recordButton.setEnabled(true);
    }

    void releaseCamera() {
        if (this.camera != null) {
            //            this.camera.lock(); // unnecessary in API >= 14
            //            //this.camera.stopPreview();
            this.camera.release();
            this.camera = null;
            this.cameraPreviewFrame.removeView(this.cameraPreview);
        }
    }

    void releaseMediaRecorder() {
        if (this.mediaRecorder != null) {
            this.mediaRecorder.reset(); // clear configuration (optional here)
            this.mediaRecorder.release();
            this.mediaRecorder = null;
        }
    }

    void releaseResources() {
        this.releaseMediaRecorder();
        this.releaseCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        this.releaseResources();
    }
    @Override
    public void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();
        this.releaseCamera();
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        this.releaseCamera();
    }

    // gets called by the button press
    public void startRecording(final View v) {
        Log.d(TAG, "startRecording()");
        // we need to unlock the camera so that mediaRecorder can use it\\
        //      this.camera.unlock(); // unnecessary in API >= 14
        // now we can initialize the media recorder and set it up with our
        // camera
        this.camera.stopPreview();
        this.camera.release();
        this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        //        this.mediaRecorder.setCamera(this.camera);
        this.mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        this.mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        ////        this.mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
        this.mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK,
                CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
        //        this.mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(320, 240);
        //       this.mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(15);
        //        this.mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        //        this.mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
        //        this.mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        //        this.mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
        //        if (CamcorderProfile.hasProfile(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_1080P))
        //          this.mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_1080P));
        //        else
        //            if (CamcorderProfile.hasProfile(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_720P))
        //              this.mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_720P));
        //            else
        //                if (CamcorderProfile.hasProfile(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P))
        //                  this.mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P));
        this.mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(this.initFile().getAbsolutePath());
        this.mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(this.cameraPreview.getHolder().getSurface());
        //      mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration((int) 1800);
        try {      
            //this.toggleButtons(true);

            String sec=String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()) ;
            //int seconds =Integer.parseInt(sec);

            String toast =String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()) +" Recording"; 
            Toast.makeText(this, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(sec.equals("1")){

                this.recordButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                this.mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(1000);
                this.mediaRecorder.prepare();
                // start the actual recording
                // throws IllegalStateException if not prepared
                this.mediaRecorder.start();
                // this.recordButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                this.recordButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        stopRecording(v);
                    }
                },1000);
            }
            else if(sec.equals("2")){

                this.recordButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                this.mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(2000);
                this.mediaRecorder.prepare();
                // start the actual recording
                // throws IllegalStateException if not prepared
                this.mediaRecorder.start();

                // this.recordButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                this.recordButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        stopRecording(v);
                    }
                },2000);
            }

            else{

                //this.mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(5000);
                this.toggleButtons(true);
                this.mediaRecorder.prepare();
                //start the actual recording
                // throws IllegalStateException if not prepared
                this.mediaRecorder.start();
                // stopRecording(v);
                // enable the stop button by indicating that we are recording
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.wtf(TAG, "Failed to prepare MediaRecorder", e);
            Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            this.releaseResources();
        }
    }

    // gets called by the button press
    public void stopRecording(View v) {
        Log.d(TAG, "stopRecording()");
        assert this.mediaRecorder != null;
        try {
            this.mediaRecorder.stop();
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.saved, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
            // we are no longer recording
            this.toggleButtons(false);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            // the recording did not succeed
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to record", e);
            if (this.file != null && this.file.exists() && this.file.delete()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Deleted " + this.file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
            return;
        } finally {
            this.releaseMediaRecorder();
        }
        if (this.file == null || !this.file.exists()) {
            Log.w(TAG, "File does not exist after stop: " + this.file.getAbsolutePath());
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Going to display the video: " + this.file.getAbsolutePath());
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, VideoPlaybackActivity.class);
            intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
            super.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    private File initFile() {
        File dir = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() +
                Utils.OUR_TEMP_FOLDER);
        if (!dir.exists() && !dir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.wtf(TAG, "Failed to create storage directory: " + dir.getAbsolutePath());
            Toast.makeText(VideoCaptureActivity.this, R.string.cannot_record, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            this.file = null;
        } else {
            this.file = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath(), new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "yyyyMMddHHmmss'.mp4'").format(new Date()));
        }
        return this.file;
    }

    private class seekListener implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener
    {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            if (fromUser == true)
            {
                Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
                p.setZoom(progress);
                camera.setParameters(p);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }
}
```

My camera prewiew is as follows

```
 CameraPreview.java:

 public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
     private static final String TAG = "CameraPreview";

     private final Camera camera;

     @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
         super(context);
         Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
         List<String> focusModes = params.getSupportedFocusModes();
         if (focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO)) 
             params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);
         else
             if (focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO)) 
                 params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
         camera.setParameters(params);
         this.camera = camera;
         super.getHolder().addCallback(this);
         // required for API <= 11
         super.getHolder().setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
     }

     public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
         Log.d(TAG, "surfaceCreated()");
         // now that we have the surface, we can start the preview
         try {

             this.camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
             this.camera.startPreview();
         } catch (IOException e) {
             Log.wtf(TAG, "Failed to start camera preview", e);
         }
     }

     public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
         // we will release the camera preview in our activity before this
         // happens
         Log.d(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed()");
     }

     public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
         // our activity runs with screenOrientation="landscape" so we don't
         // care about surface changes
        Parameters params = camera.getParameters();



         Log.d(TAG, "surfaceChanged()");
     }
 }
```

I dont know what went wrong camera is working fine but the UI is visible at start but invisible after some time but the preview remains and if ii clicked on to the button which is invisible it works .so  the control works but cant see.

Comment: Diapering? It should take a dump :P

Comment: some spelling mistakes .spare me for that ..my problem is the camera UI is dispersing off after some time when  camera is started .

Comment: @user1941148, next time, please atleast upload some good formatting code.

Comment: Are you wanting to capture pictures on invisible camera?